# Auto deploy war file (backdoor/shell) to particular folder

Tags: penetration-test, java

1. I am in the midst of a pentest. I have managed to uploaded a war shell (backdoor) in `c:\test\` which is automatically deployed in a folder, for example `c:\test\tmpbrowser.war`.
2. The application which I am testing and its files which are accessible are installed in `c:\approot\extracted\`.
3. Now what I want to arrange is that, when I upload a war file to `C:\test\`, it will get deployed to `C:\approot\extracted\`.

Is this possible?

Comment: And we should help you hack into computers because...?

Comment: If you are able to run the file in its current location, can you recreated the file in the location you want? Or, is a scenario of, "I uploaded a file, but it's not in a location that I can control. How can I get the OS to move it for me?"

Answer (score 1):

With Linux if you had a shell you could symlink the paths together however I'm not sure if there's any method of doing this on Windows.. can you execute a file to move it for you?

Please define the restraints you are working with and what you have access to

Comment: You can create symlinks in Windows as well with `mklink /j srcfolder dstfolder`

Comment: I am on windows environment and the shell is just uploaded and getting deployed but I am not able to access the shell and execute commands, so to access the shell I want to deploy it in the path which is accessible.

Comment: Does any other program use the folder your uploading to? Or is it like a temporary folder just created to upload this file to?

Comment: no other program is not using the folder. I uploaded a file and it gets deployed in the same folder.